# Site not working in ie78

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

If you take a look at http://nicky.dis-play.dk, the site works fine in Chrome, FF, Safari and IE9, however, in IE7 and IE8 the site doesn't work, and I cant seem to figure out where the problem is... :( 
Any ideas to where it goes wrong?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is never a sufficient problem description.

Comment: Looks like HTML5 elements are not styled. HTML5 Shiv should be included with Modernizr, so these elements should work. The problem is likely there.

Comment: There's also bad markup : it lacks a closing <form> tag around line 36.

Comment: Review your errors [HERE](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnicky.dis-play.dk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3). I visually tested your site using Chrome Frame Plugin on IE8 and see nothing that stands out, other than 1 missing photo in the slider. No Chrome console errors reported.

Comment: Looked like it was the modernizr, forgotten to include shiv :)  Thx :)

Comment: @mdi, +1. Also, create an Answer since it was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to include HTML5 Shiv in your Modernizr custom build.

Without it, IE7 and IE8 can't style the new HTML5 elements used on this website (`<header>`, `<nav>`)

(see comments)

Answer (score 0):

Hi think you can used this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" type="text/css"> // all css link
<script src="/static/js/libs/modernizr.custom.js" type="javascript/text"> // all script link
```